How does compiling dependent types work?
Consider the following dependently-typed function:
fill : n : Nat -> a -> Vector n a

What happens if you don't know what values n could be at compile time?
Wouldn't you have to monomorphise (instantiate) fill for every value of Nat?
Also wouldn't you have to monomorphise every call site of fill?
let vec = fill n 1

would become
switch(n)
case 1: let vec = fill n 1
case 2: let vec = fill n 1
...
case NatMax: let vec = fill n 1

How does this combinatorial explosion get constrained?

I believe the answer to "how do you monomorphize dependently-typed functions" is "you typically don't". You might be interested in how Swift (and most languages other than C++ and Rust) compile generics - there are many benefits to doing things mostly-dynamically and occasionally-monomorphically.

That blog post is actually a very good answer to the question https://faultlore.com/blah/swift-abi/ thanks!

While it’s possible to monomorphise if n is statically known, it’s not necessary just to compile the function.
Typically in a dependently typed language you have a “pi” quantifier, where f : Π(x : A). B[x] indicates that f is a function from an input value x of type A, to an output of a type B[x] that can depend on x.
The representation of f can vary based on A and B, and how the parameter x is used.

If B[x] doesn’t mention x at all, this is a non-dependent function type, f : A → B. That’s not the case for fill, because n : Nat is mentioned in a -> Vector n a.

If f doesn’t inspect the value of x, this is a parametric type—commonly A will be a kind like Type, and then this is a generic “for all” type ∀(x : A). B[x]. In fill, a : Type can be quantified in this way, but n : Nat can’t—we need to use the value of n to construct the resulting vector.

Therefore this is a “runtime-relevant” quantifier—it will become an ordinary value parameter, passed in at runtime.


One of the challenges of implementing a dependently typed language is figuring out how to avoid keeping such values around at runtime when they’re not needed.

This topic is related to a common misconception about dependent types, that they couldn’t possibly depend on runtime values. But of course they can!
For example, you can construct a vector of static length from a dynamic input list xs, and its dynamically computed length, length xs. You would then have a pair of a length and a vector of that length, whatever it may be, in the form of a sigma type Σ(n : Nat). Vector n A.
The compiler doesn’t need to know the concrete value of n, it just knows that there’s some relationship between the elements of this pair, represented by the variable n. If you want to make assumptions about n—say, that it’s nonzero—the compiler just needs to check that you’ve inserted an appropriate runtime test first.
In Idris you would check whether “decidable equality” decEq n 0 returns Yes zero or No nonzero, where zero and nonzero are dummy “proof objects” that you can name and deal with explicitly, and pass to other functions—say, a division function that forces you to check for a zero denominator before calling it.
In languages with “flow typing”, those proof objects are built-in and implicit. So you may only need to write if (n != 0) { … } for the compiler to know that n is nonzero within that block, but you can’t extend the system with new types of checks.
